How to add a satellite and show its orbital path around the globe using CesiumJs?
I am creating a small project using CesiumJs. I want to add a satellite and the orbit of the satellite should be visible. I managed to add an entity as a red dot that resembles the satellite, now I want it to revolve around the globe. I am new to this, I have looked through the Cesium Documentation multiple times but most of the examples don't seem to work.
If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!
I have tried to refer some exmples from Sandcastle but they are not working.

This official example has satellites

Please see this code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Satellite</title>
        <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.117/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.117/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/satellite.js/4.1.4/satellite.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>

        <script>
            const { BoundingSphere, Cartesian3, Color, defined, JulianDate, Matrix3, Matrix4, Transforms, Viewer } =
                window.Cesium;

            const CesiumMath = Cesium.Math;

            const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
                shouldAnimate: true
            });

            const object = viewer.entities.add({
                position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(0, 0),
                model: {
                    uri: "./weixin.gltf",
                    minimumPixelSize: 128,
                    maximumScale: 20000
                }
            });

            const tleLine1 = "1 25544U 98067A   19156.50900463  .00003075  00000-0  59442-4 0  9992";
            const tleLine2 = "2 25544  51.6433  59.2583 0008217  16.4489 347.6017 15.51174618173442";

            // Initialize a satellite record
            const satrec = satellite.twoline2satrec(tleLine1, tleLine2);

            viewer.clock.multiplier = 1000; // speed of the simulation

            const earthRotation = false;

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485298/is-there-a-way-to-configure-cesium-entities-to-be-displayed-as-icrf

            const viewInInertial = true;

            function updateCamera(time) {
                const camera = viewer.scene.camera;

                const icrfToFixed = Transforms.computeIcrfToFixedMatrix(time);

                if (icrfToFixed) {
                    const offset = Cartesian3.clone(camera.position);
                    const transform = Matrix4.fromRotationTranslation(icrfToFixed);

                    if (earthRotation) {
                        camera.lookAtTransform(transform, offset);
                    }
                }
            }

            function onPreRender(scene, time) {
                updateCamera(time);
                updatePosition(time);
            }

            function updatePosition(julianDate) {
                const date = JulianDate.toDate(julianDate);

                const positionAndVelocity = satellite.propagate(satrec, date);

                const gmst = satellite.gstime(date);

                const positionEci = positionAndVelocity.position;
                const positionGd = satellite.eciToGeodetic(positionEci, gmst);

                const longitude = positionGd.longitude;
                const latitude = positionGd.latitude;
                const height = positionGd.height;

                const positionInFixed = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
                    CesiumMath.toDegrees(longitude),
                    CesiumMath.toDegrees(latitude),
                    height
                );

                if (viewInInertial) {
                    const fixedToIcrf = Transforms.computeFixedToIcrfMatrix(julianDate);

                    let positionInInertial = new Cartesian3();

                    if (defined(fixedToIcrf)) {
                        positionInInertial = Matrix3.multiplyByVector(fixedToIcrf, positionInFixed, positionInInertial);
                    }

                    object.position.setValue(positionInInertial);
                } else {
                    object.position.setValue(positionInFixed);
                }
            }

            viewer.scene.preRender.addEventListener(onPreRender); // enable Earth rotation

            /*
    if(!earthRotation){
        viewer.trackedEntity = object;
    }
    */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


